# Error calling Connect-PnPOnline in Function App

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I'm troubleshooting an issue, where calling Connect-PnPOnline caused a strange error in an Azure tenant:

**ERROR: Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.**

This app runs a PowerShell code to connect to a SharePoint site with supplied credentials.

```
$SiteUrl = 'https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/News'
$ServiceUser = '<user>@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
$ServicePassword = '<the password>'
$ServiceCredentials = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ServiceUser, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ServicePassword -AsPlainText -Force)))
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $ServiceCredentials
```

- The error message appears when Connect-PnPOnline is called.
- 'PnP.PowerShell' = '1.2.0' is specified in requirements.psd1.
- Tried to change the credential to an admin acccount but still same error

To check if this is a wider problem, I created a function app in a second tenant to connect to a SharePoint site in this second tenant. The function app in this tenant ran without problem.

Out of curiousity, I swapped the site url and the credential between the two apps, so that

- the app in the first prblematic tenant willl try to connect to the SharePoint site in the second tenant
- the app in the second tenant will connect to the SharePoint site in the first tenant.

To my surprise, the app in the second tenant then fails and the app in the first tenant ran successfully.

So I though, that'd be something that's causing PnP.PowerShell not able to connect to the SP site in the first tenant. So I tried to run the code in my local PowerShell ISE, and it was able to connect to the SharePoint site in the first tenant without problem.

So in summary

| App Hosted In | Connecting to SP Site In | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tenant 1 | Tenant 1 | Fail |
| Tenant 1 | Tenant 2 | Success |
| Tenant 2 | Tenant 1 | Fail |
| Tenant 2 | Tenant 2 | Success |
| PS ISE | Tenant 1 | Success |

I am hoping someone will know how the issue can be fixed in tenant 1!

Kind regards

Comment: Are both of your function App on V3.0 of the azure function runtime ? To me your error seems like it could be due to a PS runtime discrepancy but then, the result you show do not confirm my theory. Neverthless, since you did not mention it, I'd recommend confirm both the azure function app are running on the same runtime.

Comment: Any reason why you are using 1.2.0 ? Can you try the latest (1.9.0) ? Does it change anything. Also, check https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/azurefunctions.html and make sure both the function app are configured according to the doc (even though based on results you have it might not be relevant). I don't have an answer, I'm just fishing...

Comment: @SagePourpre The runtime version of the original function app that has the issue is 3.4.2.0. For testing to compare results between tenant 1 and tenant 2, I created new function app in both tenant so both has same runtime version 4.1.3.17473, and PnP.PowerShell 1.2.0. I'm using PnP.PowerShell 1.2.0 as only because the app was created sometime last year by someone else. I guess 1.2.0 was the latest version back then. I can give a go at 1.9, but then 1.2 is working fine in tenant 2...

Comment: @SagePourpre So I went ahead and updated the function app in tenant 1 to use pnp powershell 1.9.0. This indeed got rid of the error and the process that depends on this function app is working again. Thank you for the suggestion.

Although I still don't understand why using 1.2.0 only fails connecting to SharePoint in tenant 1, and no problem connecting to SharePoint in tenant 2. 

Comment: NIce. Glad it helped. Looking very quickly at the PNP module on Github, there is a mention about that error: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/39. It might or might not be relevant with what was happening to you. In any case, it looks like they changed whatever was conflicting at some point based on your success with 1.9.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

We had the same problem after changing the latest stable **PnP PowerShell version (1.9.0)**, the issue was cleared.

> I still don't understand why using 1.2.0 only fails connecting to SharePoint in tenant 1, and no problem connecting to SharePoint in tenant 2

[image]
Thanks to @[Sage Pourpre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934946/sage-pourpre), your comments helped a lot to fix the problem.
In addition, if you still facing the issue please follow the workaround.
The issue happens because **Azure AD** is not compatible with **(PowerShell 7.*)**

1. Check PowerShell version

```
     $PSVersionTable
```

2. Install/Update Azure AD Module

```
//Install
Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser
//update
Update-Module  AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser
```

3. Import AD Module

```
Import-Module AzureAD
```

4. Connect Azure AD

```
//Connect AD
Connect-AzureAD
```

5. Sometimes using the Old version of Modules can impact the issue so try to Uninstall the module and install the latest one. Check [Link1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8242#issuecomment-905897625) & [Link 2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/232#issuecomment-536744760)

Refer [here](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/azurefunctions.html) for more information